# How do I take a column of String type decimals in Pyspark and round them to the nearest 50 value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a column in a dataset called "X":

| X |
| --- |
| "2893.324" |
| "1058.112" |
| "5651.324" |

Im trying to make these numbers be interger values that round to nearest 50

Output should be this:

| X | results |
| --- | --- |
| "2893.324" | 2900 |
| "1058.112" | 1050 |
| "5651.324" | 5650 |

Comment: please forgive my ability to write the table looking format in this, i've been confused on how to make that work, i hope this example suffices

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dividing by 50, rounding to nearest integer and then multiplying again.

no need for user-defined-functions, `pyspark.sql.functions` module has you covered. see suggested code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, round 

df \
.withColumn(
  "results",
  round(col("X").cast("double") / 50) * 50
)
```